# how to change style for a particular path in partition chart (D3.js)

Tags: d3.js

I Am trying to change the style for particular path, in a Partition Chart. Here is the [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/g88S7/1/) for the code.

here on Button click m calling a function **changeStyle()**,  where m selecting all path & iterating them for getting the path between the given range.

```
function changeStyle(){
    d3.selectAll('path')
    .each(function(path){
        if(inRange(path)){
            path.style('opacity', 1);
        }
    });
}
function inRange(path){
    if(path.size>7000 && path.size<7500){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now when range meets criteria i want to add some style to that path like opacity or color. But m getting error **Object # has no method 'style'** . Here m not sure what is the proper way for doing this. Can any one help to change the style for that particular path?

Comment: if m doing d3.selectAll('path').style('opacity', 0.1); its working But when iterating then its not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/Xcbgd/)**

```
function changeStyle(){

d3.selectAll('path')
.each(function(pat,i){
    if(inRange(pat)){
         d3.select(this).style('opacity', 0);
    }
  });
}
function inRange(pat){
    if(pat.size>7000 && pat.size<7500){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: you already defined Path,so in each function you can use any variable name except path ..

Comment: This is not an appropriate solution. You shouldn't reference `path[0][i]` directly, and you don't have to. You can use the `this` object.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer here is not really appropriate. The use of `path[0][i]` instead of works in this case, but could break in selections with multiple parents. The idiomatic d3 way to manipulate a DOM element from within an `each()` function is via: `d3.select(this)`. The `this` object is the `<path>` element associated with the given datum.

```
d3.selectAll('path')
  .each(function(pat,i){
    if(inRange(pat)){
      d3.select(this).style('opacity')[0]
    }
  });
```

[See jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g88S7/2/)

If you wish to manipulate the element directly, kind of like Manoj suggested, you would use `this.style.opacity="0"`.

Finally, instead of using `each`, you could use `filter`:

```
d3.selectAll('path')
  .filter(inRange)
  .style('opacity', 0)
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g88S7/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `.attr("opacity", "1")` ?

Also, when you want to change style on SVG object, it's always better to affect particular classes and use CSS to customize them as in :

```
path.attr("class", "in-range");
```

and in your CSS file :

```
path.in-range {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: still m getting the same error "Object #<Object> has no method 'attr' " for both the case